# VBA Copy all lines with matching ID

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, one with scripts for testing, the other with user names and the script numbers they need to test. I would like to create a sheet for each user that only contains the scripts they need to test. Code below is creating the tabs correctly but only copying over script 1 for each user.

Sheet Script:

| Script Number | Script Name | Order | Step Name | Instructions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Add Contact | 1 | Login to system |  |
| 1 |  | 2 | Open a Transaction Record | You can use global search |
| 1 |  | 3 | Click on New Contact |  |
| 1 |  | 4 | Enter Information |  |
| 1 |  | 5 | Click Save |  |
| 2 | Attach a file | 1 | Login to system |  |
| 2 |  | 2 | Find a contact | You can use global search |
| 2 |  | 3 | Etc |  |

User Sheet:

| User | Scripts |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jackie | 1 | 3 | 9 |  |  |
| Eli | 3 | 7 | 9 | 15 |  |

In the example above I want scripts 1,3,9 to appear on a tab called Jackie, and 3,7,9,15 on one called Eli

Sample Code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim lastrow As Long, lastColumn As Long

    lastrow = Sheets("Users").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rngScript As Range
    Dim rngUser As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim found As Range
    Dim CopytoRow As Long, UserRow As Long

    UserRow = 2
   
    Set rngUser = Range(Sheets("Users").Cells(UserRow, 2), Sheets("Users").Cells(UserRow, 2).End(xlToLeft))
    Set rngScript = Range(Sheets("Scripts").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Scripts").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
    
    For r = 2 To lastrow
    
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    CopytoRow = 2
        
    For Each cell In rngScript

    Set found = rngUser.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
             
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
             
    cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CopytoRow)
                
    CopytoRow = CopytoRow + 1
    
    End If

    Next cell
        
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Users").Cells(UserRow, 1).Value
    UserRow = UserRow + 1
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to set `rngUser` and `rngScript` *inside* the loop, using `r` as the row, not `UserRow` or a hard-coded `2`

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried that. I copied ```rngUser``` and ```rngScript``` under the ```For r = 2 to lastrow``` line and substituted ```r``` everywhere ```userrow```was being used. It copied script 1 for Jackie and 3 for Eli but no others

Comment: See my suggestion below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe not the most efficient way, but simplest I think:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsScripts As Worksheet, wsUsers As Worksheet
    Dim rngScripts As Range, rngUsers As Range, rw As Range, usr, m
    Dim rngHeaders As Range, c As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsScripts = wb.Worksheets("Scripts")
    Set wsUsers = wb.Worksheets("Users")

    Set rngHeaders = wsScripts.Range("A1:E1") 'headers for new sheets
    Set rngScripts = wsScripts.Range("A2:E" & wsScripts.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rngUsers = wsUsers.Range("A2:A" & wsUsers.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each rw In rngScripts.Rows    'loop over the script rows
        For Each c In rngUsers.Cells  'loop over the users
            m = Application.Match(rw.Cells(1).Value, c.EntireRow, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then 'user has this script assigned
                With GetWorksheet(wb, c.Value, rngHeaders)
                    'copy script row to next empty cell
                    rw.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    Next rw
End Sub

'Return the worksheet named `wsName` from workbook `wb`
'If the sheet doesn't exist then create it, and optionally copy
'    headers from `rngHeaders` to the new sheet
Function GetWorksheet(wb As Workbook, wsName As String, _
                      Optional rngHeaders As Range = Nothing) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next  'ignore error if no sheet with this name
    Set GetWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0       'stop ignoring errors
    If GetWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetWorksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
        'copy headers if provided
        If Not rngHeaders Is Nothing Then rngHeaders.Copy GetWorksheet.Range("A1")
        GetWorksheet.Name = wsName 'name the new sheet
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

### Export Data to Separate Worksheets

**Description**

- This code is designed to export data from a source worksheet to multiple destination worksheets, where each destination worksheet corresponds to a unique user, as determined by the data in a lookup worksheet.

**The Code**

```
Sub ExportByUsers()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Store the data from the lookup worksheet in an array.
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Sheets("Users")
    
    Dim lrg As Range, lrCount As Long, lcCount As Long
    
    With lws.UsedRange
        lrCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
        lcCount = .Columns.Count
        If lrCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set lrg = .Resize(lrCount).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
    End With
    
    Dim lData(): lData = lrg.Value
    
    ' Store the unique users from the first column in a dictionary as a key,
    ' and store the script numbers in same row in a collection, in the item
    ' associated with each key.
    
    Dim lDict As Object: Set lDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, lStr As String
    
    For lr = 1 To lrCount
        lStr = lData(lr, 1)
        If Len(lStr) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            If Not lDict.Exists(lStr) Then Set lDict(lStr) = New Collection
            For lc = 2 To lcCount
                If VarType(lData(lr, lc)) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                    lDict(lStr).Add lData(lr, lc)
                'Else ' is not a number; do nothing
                End If
            Next lc
        'Else ' is blank
        End If
    Next lr
            
    ' Store the data from the 1st column of the source worksheet in an array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Scripts")
    
    Dim srg As Range, shrg As Range, srCount As Long, scCount As Long
    
    With sws.UsedRange
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        scCount = .Columns.Count
        Set shrg = .Rows(1)
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Columns(1).Value
    
    ' Store the unique script numbers from the array in a dictionary as a key,
    ' and store the row ranges of the numbers in a unioned range object,
    ' in the item associated with each key.
    
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sVal, sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sVal = sData(sr, 1)
        If VarType(sVal) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            If Not sDict.Exists(sVal) Then
                Set sDict(sVal) = srg.Rows(sr)
            Else
                Set sDict(sVal) = Union(sDict(sVal), srg.Rows(sr))
            End If
        'Else ' is not a number; do nothing
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Create a copy of the source worksheet to be used as a template
    ' i.e. to be repeatedly copied for each user.
    
    sws.Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    With tws.UsedRange
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Clear ' clear all except headers
    End With
    
    ' For each key in the lookup dictionary, create a copy
    ' of the template worksheet, the destination worksheet,
    ' and copy the corresponding ranges to it.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dsh As Object, dws As Worksheet, surg As Range, drg As Range
    Dim lKey, lItem
    
    For Each lKey In lDict.Keys
        ' Create a copy of the template worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dsh = wb.Sheets(CStr(lKey))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
               dsh.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Set dsh = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
        tws.Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        dws.Name = lKey
        Set drg = dws.UsedRange.Rows(1).Offset(1)
        ' Combine the ranges in a unioned range.
        For Each lItem In lDict(lKey)
            If sDict.Exists(lItem) Then
                If surg Is Nothing Then
                    Set surg = sDict(lItem)
                Else
                    Set surg = Union(surg, sDict(lItem))
                End If
            End If
        Next lItem
        ' Copy the unioned range.
        If Not surg Is Nothing Then
            surg.Copy drg
            Set surg = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
    Next lKey
    
    ' Delete the template worksheet.
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        tws.Delete ' delete without confirmation
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Single-user worksheets created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```